# Is it possible to open a new tab in IE when the main window is chrome | ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have an asp.net c# web application(strictly for intranet usage)
I need to open a MS word document present on a remote file share, it should be saved to the same location when saved.
I achieved this using IE, but due to security model of chrome and firefox, the file:/// opens a blank window.

Is it possible to open an IE window from the existing application in chrome/firefox?

Comment: If there was, it would get a CVE number in no time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't controll other application using javascript in browser.
If you want to open MS Word document in window browser you will need an extension for browser or you can use javascript based script witch allow to view (and optionally edit) MS Word documents. However it may be a couple differences between MS Word and javascript editor, in usage, document layout, fonts, spaces, etc..

Comment: thanks david,I dont want to open the document in the browser per se, it should be opened via ms word itself, but i was using window.open and providing the file location as url which works in ie but not in other browsers